# IBM MARS cipher test vectors

Tags: encryption, arm

Hello,

Currently I am learning ARM assembly on Raspberry Pi 1 Model B+ by writing my own implementations of AES finalists ciphers. I wanted to test my MARS implementation with IBM test vectors, but it seems that they are inconsistent. For example in these two files:

https://web.archive.org/web/20010504113019/http://www.research.ibm.com/security/test-vectors/ecb_tbl.txt

https://web.archive.org/web/20010504112041/http://www.research.ibm.com/security/test-vectors/ecb_e_m.txt

plaintext: 00000000000000000000000000000000 and key: 00000000000000000000000000000000 give two different ciphertexts: DCC07B8DFB0738D6E30A22DFCF27E886 and F28C7E672247DE249C04BE791BCE4065. My code gives DCC07B8DFB0738D6E30A22DFCF27E886 as an answer. Is this answer correct? Does anyone have more test vectors and is certain that they are correct?

List of all test vectors files: https://web.archive.org/web/20000818115416/http://www.research.ibm.com/security/test-vectors/

IBM MARS specification: https://web.archive.org/web/20000815233719/http://www.research.ibm.com/security/mars.pdf

My ARM assembly code: http://www.zenker.pl/mars/arm/mars.s

Comment: RPi 1???? If you switch to RPi3, the Cortex-A53 NEON has AES instructions that make world difference.

Comment: I do it just for fun, but I also want to have working code

Answer (score 0):

The correct is DCC07B8DFB0738D6E30A22DFCF27E886.

128-bit Test Vector:
+00000000000000000000000000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000
DCC07B8DFB0738D6E30A22DFCF27E886

https://groups.google.com/g/synergy-plus-changes/c/RIuFEbDbDUY?pli=1